# Installing SSL for third party web service communication from Azure

Tags: azure, ssl

Apologies for what is probably a question about a simple task but I'm brand new to Azure  and a little worried I get this wrong.  Actually, I have a new client and don't even have the access yet to their Azure yet have a proper look.  The question is:

My new client has an existing MVC application running on IIS within Azure.  This application must communicate with a third party SOAP (.asmx) web service that requires parts of the SOAP message to be signed using an SSL digital certificate.

So, I need to install the certificate on Azure.  My problem is that the articles I have found deal with securing the website using the certificate and Https - which I don't want.

Can someone please point me to a good article (or show here if simple enough) that shows how to install it for the purpose of communicating with this third party service?

Any help is really appreciated here so that I can hit the ground running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach for installing any certificate is the same. So you would use the same approach as you would for installing SSL certificate. So the steps would be:

- Upload the certificate first in the cloud services certificate section. Note down the certificate thumbprint.

[image]

- In Visual Studio, open up your role's properties and go to "Certificates" tab and specify that certificate thumbprint along with the certificate store location where you want this certificate to be installed.

[image]